# Why am I getting $NaN on this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, numbers, nan

I keep getting $NaN instead of a number. (Code starts on `line 155`.) How can I get a number output instead of `$NaN`.Is there a better way to debug this to determine what exactly is being returned?

```
function daysInMonth(y, m) {
  var t = new Date(y, m, 0);
  return t.getDate();
}
function daysLeftInQuater(d) {
  d = d || new Date(); // If no date supplied, use today
  var t = new Date(d); // Don't mess up supplied date if there was one
  var daysLeft = 2 - (t.getMonth() % 3);

  do {
    daysLeft += daysInMonth(t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth() + 1) - t.getDate();
    t.setMonth(t.getMonth() + 1);
    t.setDate(1);
  } while (t.getMonth() % 3)

  return daysLeft;      
}
function getQuarter(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var m = Math.floor(d.getMonth()/3) + 2;
  return m > 4? m - 5 : m;
}
function hoa_letsgo(){
var amt_due = $("#user_ad").val();
var qma_val = $("#qma_select").val();
if (qma_val == 1){//Q
var cur_year = $("#year").val(); var cur_day = $("#day").val();
var cur_month = $("#month").val(); var now = new Date(cur_month, cur_day, cur_year);
var days_left = daysLeftInQuater(cur_month);
var ind_amt = amt_due / 4;
var day_amt = amt_due / 360;
var quarter = getQuarter(now);
var am_cred = ind_amt * quarter;
var final_cred = am_cred + (day_amt * days_left);
final_cred = final_cred - amt_due;
final_cred = final_cred.toFixed(2)
$("#credit").html("$" + addCommas(final_cred));
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit and post some code here?

Comment: You probably aren't going to get any good responses with the question you have here.  move some of the relevant code into the question and try to ask a more pionted question.  What have you tried?  Why do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pulling a value out of a textbox gives you a string. you cannot perform some arithmetic functions with strings because the operator is overloaded to perform a different operation. for example, the addition operator `+` will perform string concatenation if either operand is a string.

wrap all of your `.val()` calls with a `parseInt(..., 10);` or `parseFloat(..., 10);` and it should fix your issue.